The merge process could not retrieve generation information at the subscriber. If this failure persists, reinitiatlise the subscription
I have merge replication setup and all of a sudden am getting this error:
*The merge process could not retrieve generation information at the subscriber. If this g=failure persists, reinitiatlise the subscription(Source: MSSQL_REPL,
Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147201004)
TCP Provider: The specified network name is nolonger available. (Source: MSSQL Server, Error number 64)
Communication link failure Source: MSSQL Server, Error number 64*

Anyone who can assist?

Looks like the publisher can’t establish a connection to the subscription server. Check the network connection, firewall etc.. first. Is it possible to run a query from the publishing server with select * from subscriptionservername.subscriptiondatabase.dbo.tablex (replace with your names)
